# Why would IDirect3DDevice9::Release return S_FALSE?

Tags: com, directx, direct3d, directx-9, direct3d9

When I call the Release method for my Direct3D9 device it returns S_FALSE but I can't find anything that explains why this value would be returned.

From what I can gather, S_FALSE means that it has succeeded but hasn't had to do anything but I only release once.

I also don't think the method does succeed as I am left with a fullscreen DirectX window even after the window has been destroyed and the device released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IUnknown::Release` does not return a `HRESULT` as you assumed, it instead returns a `ULONG` indicating outstanding reference count (of this COM object).

Comment: Ah, I found I hadn't released one of my textures which would have had a reference to it. That caused Release to return 1 which is the same as S_FALSE. Thank you.